# Android, "Error in an XML file: aborting build."

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-layout

I am coding an Android project and get the error:

```
Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

This is the XML code referenced in the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
   <string name="app_name">Sudoku</string>
   <string name="main_title">Android Sudoku</string>
   <string name="continue_label">Continue</string>
   <string name="new_game_label">New Game</string>
   <string name="about_label">About</string>
   <string name="exit_label">Exit</string>
</resources>
```

What does this error mean and how can I find out where the error is?

Comment: PPS.: in the string.out.xml file are nooooo mistakes... its empty

Comment: When you open XML file editor, you will see red marks. Mouseover on it you will get message. (assuming you are using eclipse)

Comment: What type of error you are getting. And also if you file name is string.out.xml rename it strings.xml

Comment: thx... i had to clean up my project and run the activity instead of the *.xml file

Comment: strings.xml is not the only xml file. look for error in layout xml too, your current string.xml is fine. no error, so it can be the other xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried Gabriels answer with no success. I ended up saving my strings.xml file elsewhere, deleting the one in the project, opening the AndroidManifest.xml **(this was key)**, restarting Eclipse, and adding the file back worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

This error occurs when you try to run the application with the xml file open.

Close all xml files, open the .java file and try to run the application again.

Don't forget to delete the ".out.xml" file.

Comment: Open the AndroidManifest.xml before restarting.